# How to disable public holidays from datepicker with dayjs

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, dayjs

I have a datepicker where I use @material-ui/picker. I want to disable all the public/bank holidays from the datepicker. I'm using day with days.js. But im not quite sure on how to proceed. I have my datepicker:

```js
import nl from 'dayjs/locale/nl';

<MateriaUIPicker utils={dateJS} locale={nl}>
  <DatePicker />
</MateriaUIPicker>
```

But, I want to disable all nl public holidays (official holidays in Netherlands) in my datepicker. But it does not work. Can I please get some help with this?

Comment: `dateJS` probably doesn't know all the Dutch holidays, so'll need to find some sort of list and implement your custom logic.

Comment: @0stone0 is there a easy way of doing this? without implementing all of the dates manually?